# How can I place a block randomly around my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I downloaded a lucky block mod and I want to place them randomly in my world.
Is there a command to do this? I'd prefer the entire world to be affected but if it's just around 200 blocks then that's fine.

Comment: Hey thank you very much! But i have no idea how commands work, can you pls post the commands for it? Would be obliged.

Comment: I assume you commented on the wrong post so I'll reply here. All the links to the information are below, take a moment to learn how commands do work and it'll help you a lot more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one command but you could do it with a few:

1. Summon large amounts of entities. Armour stands are probably the best as they can't move.
2. Use the `spreadplayers` command to distribute them around the world.
3. Use the `execute` command to `setblock` your lucky block at each armour stands' position.
4. Use the `kill` command to remove all the armour stands.

Links on each commands' syntax are below.

[Spreadplayers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spreadplayers)

[Execute](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute)

[Setblock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/setblock)

[Kill](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/kill)